# Como listar os links simbólicos de uma pasta no Linux?

Tags: linux, bash

Estou usando uma ferramenta para [deploy](http://deployer.org/docs/recipes) em PHP.

Quando eu utilizo o comando, alguns links simbólicos são criados para determinadas pastas.

Como vou executar esse comando num servidor Linux, gostaria de saber se existe algum comando para listar todos os links simbólicos criados na pasta.

Com o comando `ls` não estou conseguindo diferenciar entre pastas e links

Como posso fazer isso no Linux?

Comment: tentou `ls -la` ? Dá pra ver quem é link pelo `->`

Comment: O que faz isso?

Comment: é o `ls`, mas com as flags pra "listar em lista" e mostrar tudo. Se preferir tem o `find . -type l -ls`, que restringe somente a links

Comment: Responde ae amigo

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/1/ls e http://linux.die.net/man/1/find

Comment: Quem deu o -1 poderia informar como eu poderia melhorar a pergunta?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se for só para visualizar, pode usar o `ls` mesmo:

```
ls -l
```

- a opção `-l` é a "listagem longa", que mostra os detalhes

Os links aparecerão com indicação da origem (`->`).

> http://linux.die.net/man/1/ls

Se quiser filtrar melhor a listagem, pode usar o `find`:

```
find . -type l -ls
```

- `.` é o diretório corrente. Pode trocar pelo caminho específico, se preferir.
- o `-type` é um filtro de tipo de arquivo. O `l`, como você deve ter imaginado, é o tipo "link simbólico".
- o `-ls` no caso é apenas um auxiliar aqui, para mostrar os caracteres especiais "escapados", de modo a ficarem legiveis.

> http://linux.die.net/man/1/find

Comment: Com o `ls -l` então daria para combinar com um `grep "\->"`:p

Comment: Se for pra pesquisar mesmo, melhor o `find`. Eu acho que o ls é bom pra ir "no zóio" só. Mas dá pra filtrar com grep sem problemas.